# Move Email using filter like Thunderbird

Tags: gmail-api, email

I think all is in the title.

I would like to sort my email using the import filter options.
I have take a look here (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/filters) but nothing look like good to perform folder change.

I have try to import msgFilterRules.dat file from thunderbird folder but not an xml format.

If any one got an idea....

Comment: Have you checked [Managing Filters](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings)?

Comment: Yes, actions can just able to Tag, unTag or forward to a specific email but not moving email received to an other folder.